# Why notification color is different?

Tags: android, colors, notifications, android-notifications

I am trying to set color to my notification action btns with next code:

.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ff7900"))

```
NotificationCompat.Builder(service, CHANEL_ID)
            .setColor(Color.parseColor("#ff7900"))
            .setContentIntent(piClick)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
            .setShowWhen(false)
```

here is result: 
[image]

but the real color is different - "#d14d00".

any ideas why it is happen and how it can be fixed?

Answer (score -1):

you can try with this

```
 builder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.yourColor));
```

or try with this

```
 builder.setColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.yourColor));
```

Comment: If you not familiar with the question, than please do not answer ;-) your suggestions doesn't do anything different from my code.

Comment: @AndriyAntonov what happens?

Comment: @AndriyAntonov are you want to change notification text color or icon?

Comment: @AndriyAntonov in which version of android you are trying?

Comment: setColor() changing appIcon, appName, and actionBtns. thats exactly what I am trying to change